# ImportError: cannot import name 'texttospeech' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Tags: python

Trying to make an extention for my discord bot that converts the input of the user's text to an audio file so that my bot can play that audio.  I just can't figure out why I can't import the *google* module.

```py
from google.cloud import texttospeech


def synthesize_text(text):

    """Synthesizes speech from the input string of text."""

    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

    input_text = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text=text)

    # Note: the voice can also be specified by name.
    # Names of voices can be retrieved with client.list_voices().

    voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(

        language_code="en-US",
        name="en-US-Standard-C",
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE,
    )

    audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3)

    response = client.synthesize_speech(request={"input": input_text, "voice": voice, "audio_config": audio_config})

    # The response's audio_content is binary.

    with open("output.mp3", "wb") as out:


        out.write(response.audio_content)

        print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

Answer (score 11):

As stated in the comment above, you need to first install the library on your machine before calling the function within your app.

```
pip install google-cloud-texttospeech
```

[Read through official documentation on usage if required.](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-texttospeech/)

Based on your code I believe that you have the following item checked off as well.

In order to use this library, you first need to go through the following steps:

1. Select or create a Cloud Platform project.
2. Enable billing for your project.
3. Enable the Cloud Text-to-Speech API.
4. Setup Authentication.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
pip install google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

pip install google-cloud-texttospeech
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this form:

```
pip install google-cloud-texttospeech
```

This not:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-texttospeech
```